# Why does the DocumentFilter not give the intended result?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, documentfilter

I figure this must be a simple mistake in the code or a misunderstanding on my part, but I cannot get a `DocumentFilter` to detect `insertString` events.  Below is a simple filter for upper case letters, but that is not as important as the fact that the `insertString(..)` method never seems to be called!

Why is the `insertString(..)` method of the `DocumentFilter` not called?

The filter is applied to the `JTextField` at the top.  Every time `insertString(..)` is called, it should append information to the `JTextArea` in the `CENTER`.  At the moment, there is no action in the text field that causes text to be appended to the text area.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class FilterUpperCaseLetters {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    private final JTextField textField = new JTextField(25);
    private final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);

    FilterUpperCaseLetters() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        // The document filter that seems to do nothing.
        DocumentFilter capsFilter = new DocumentFilter() {
            @Override
            public void insertString(
                    DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb,
                    int offset,
                    String string,
                    AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
                textArea.append("insertString! " + string + "\n");
                if (!string.toUpperCase().equals(string)) {
                    textArea.append("Insert!\n");
                    super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
                } else {
                    textArea.append("DON'T insert!\n");
                }
            }
        };
        AbstractDocument abstractDocument
                = (AbstractDocument) textField.getDocument();
        abstractDocument.setDocumentFilter(capsFilter);

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

        ui.add(textField, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        ui.add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                FilterUpperCaseLetters o = new FilterUpperCaseLetters();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Why is `insertString` not called?"* Why should it be? Have you tried seeing in what order the methods are called?  `insertString`/`remove`/`replace` and seeing when the are called and maybe trying to see if you can determine in which conditions you need to apply your filter?

Comment: One needs to override `replace` as well :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The text components use the `replaceSelection(...)` method which will in turn invoke the `replace(...)` method of the `AbstractDocument` which will invoke the `replace(...)` method of the `DocumentFilter`.

The `insertString(...)` method of the `DocumentFilter` is only called when you use the `Document.insertString(...)` method to directly update the `Document`.

So in reality you need to override both methods to make sure the upper case conversion is done.

A simple example showing how to easily implement both methods:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class UpperCaseFilter extends DocumentFilter
{
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offs, String str, AttributeSet a)
        throws BadLocationException
    {
        replace(fb, offs, 0, str, a);
    }

    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, final int offs, final int length, final String text, final AttributeSet a)
        throws BadLocationException
    {
        if (text != null)
        {
            super.replace(fb, offs, length, text.toUpperCase(), a);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
        AbstractDocument doc = (AbstractDocument) textField.getDocument();
        doc.setDocumentFilter( new UpperCaseFilter() );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Upper Case Filter");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout( new java.awt.GridBagLayout() );
        frame.add( textField );
        frame.setSize(220, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }
}
```