# When is insertString method in document filter used?

Tags: java, swing, documentfilter

I have been playing around document filter but one thing I failed to understand is, when exactly is `insertString` method used? I have only seen it use `replace` or `remove` methods in almost every general possible scenario I can think of (copy/pasting, manual typing etc). From docs, it says:

```
Invoked prior to insertion of text into the specified Document.
```

But every method I tried of text insertion executed `replace` method.

Can someone please simplify it for me when exactly is this method used?

Comment: It's called when `Document#insertString` is called

Comment: You mean when `textField.getDocument().insertString...` is used? (just confirming)

Comment: That's one way to call it

Comment: @user3271166, check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487465/why-does-the-documentfilter-not-give-the-intended-result/31487599#31487599